# TypeScript definition files from .NET classes

Tags: typescript

Anyone know of a tool to turn C# / .NET classes into TypeScript definition files, perhaps by using reflection?

I'm using json.net to encode the C# classes, so having strongly typed defs would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse existing C# class definitions in TypeScript projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957820/how-to-reuse-existing-c-sharp-class-definitions-in-typescript-projects)

Comment: I spoke to Anders about this at \\build as Microsoft have an internal tool. I asked if they would release it and he said yes. Still waiting however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't about anything official but here is a project that seems to do something similar: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/406685

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available via nuget: http://type.litesolutions.net/

Comment: Only had a quick look, but looks good. It's reflection based I guess? Not parsing the source code