# How to generate angularjs model from c# class

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, binding, model

The angular app I am working on has several large input forms which span several pages. The data is added to an angular model which is a javascript object literal and sent to a webApi controller. The webApi parameter for my POST methods is a C# class (duh) with a lot of properties! Is there a utility which will generate the javascript from my C# class, so that my binding just works! I've googled this and failed even though it seems such a mundane task. As always thanks in advance.

Comment: Many solutions here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957820/how-to-reuse-existing-c-sharp-class-definitions-in-typescript-projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957820/how-to-reuse-existing-c-sharp-class-definitions-in-typescript-projects)

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON serialize on your JS side and deserialize on your c# side.

JS:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = 
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string jsonParam = oSerializer.Serialize(param);
```

While on your c# side you should use something like, lets say your class is Person:

C#:

```
Person person = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(param);
```

see [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on serialize\deserialize json object

Comment: Yes I could do this this but I will still have the problem of a javascript object and a C# object needing to match so the serialize/deserialize works correctly

Comment: If you take your c# object and serialize it to JSON you will have a JS object that matches your c# class.

Comment: So I'm still looking for a utility or VS extension that will do this for me rather  than some hacky code which spits out a text file somewhere which I then paste into my angular service/model

Comment: We've tended to use Deserialize to return JSON from MVC Actions or inside ViewModels. You can @Html.Raw(Model.JsonString) inside your View or use it in the return from an AJAX call. No text file included!