# Automatically generating TypeScript data contract interface from C# JSON service implementation

Tags: c#, json, web-services, typescript, datacontract

Our C# application provides a number of JSON web-services for the web app client to consume. Currently we generate that JSON reasonably manually through recursive object-to-JSON-dictionary-representation calls.

We're gradually implementing parts of our web app in TypeScript - we'd like to have TypeScript interfaces to define the shape of the JSON data the client code should expect to receive from the server.

Is there a way to automatically generate the TypeScript data contract interface definitions at compile time, based on the C# JSON service implementation?

For example, the C# code generating the JSON currently looks something like this:

```
    public class ConcreteObj
    {
        public string SimpleProperty;
        public ConcreteObj[] Children;
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, object> ConvertToScriptValue(ConcreteObj obj)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        result["simpleProperty"] = obj.SimpleProperty; // string
        result["children"] = Array.ConvertAll(obj.Children, ConvertToScriptValue); // ConcreteObj array

        return result;
    }
```

We'd like to see TypeScript similar to the following:

```
interface ConcreteObj {
    simpleProperty: string;
    children: ConcreteObj[];
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957820/how-to-reuse-existing-c-sharp-class-definitions-in-typescript-projects (especially the link to http://type.litesolutions.net/)