# How to get column's default value in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Is there a way to obtain the default value of a column in Entity Framework? I can't seem to create an Entity Data Model of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table like I would a regular table.

Ordinarily, with a `MySQLConnection`, I would do something like

`SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'columnname';`

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Get default sql value from Entity Framework class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894943/get-default-sql-value-from-entity-framework-class), so I'll quote:

In case you have access to the generated DbContext, you can use the metadata provided by the DbContext.Model instead of reflection (But you can use reflection if you set your DefaultValues using Attributes, why not! Just use `MemberInfo.CustomAttributes`)

For instance:

```
foreach (var type in db.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var defaultValue = property.Relational().DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available for Code First (which makes sense). It turns out I can do a `.Database.SqlQuery` though, I think that may serve my purposes.