# How to show the full swagger interface when using NSwag with .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, swagger-codegen, nswag, asp.net5

I am trying to familiarize with NSwag usage for .NET 5 [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). After reading, I got the impression that this documentation is outdated as it mentions methods such as `UseMvc` and `AddMvc` which are typical for .NET Core 2.1 but not for .NET 5. Anyway, here are my Configure methods (I manipulated the standard .NET 5 Web Api project automatically generated by Visual Studio 2019):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerDocument();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseOpenApi();
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

After pressing F5, the following was shown:

[image]

This is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.11.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Apparently, I "lost" the GET method of the `WeatherForecastController`. So, how to show the full swagger interface when using NSwag with .NET 5? [The code examples referred to by the docs](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger/samples), are not helping me either as these are based on old versions of .NET Core. The reason for me to use NSwag is that is "[the most popular tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61491713/1987258)" to generate typescript code for my client projects.

Comment: Can you post the code and annotations of the `WeatherForecastController` and its GET method?

Comment: @Helen It is the standard project automatically generated by Visual Studio 2019. Can be found here too: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/samples/5.x/TodoApi/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs#L12

Answer (score 2):

Click the WeatherForecast to expand the node to see the details, you will find the GET Method there.