# Web Essentials 2017 and TypeScript definition generation

Tags: c#, web-essentials

Just installed Web Essentials 2017 from the Visual Studio marketplace but the feature to create TypeScript definition from a C# class seems to be missing. In Web Essentials 2015, I would right mouse over the C# class file and there would be an option "Create TypeScript Intellisense file".

I checked the project change log and it shows that the TypeScript definition file generator was implemented in 1.2 and the installed version is 1.5.8.

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2017/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

What did I miss?

Comment: No need to create a new tag. The extension is not specific to a Visual Studoi release, so no need to version the tag.

Answer (score 6):

Web Essentials is now split into multiple extensions. To install the TypeScript generator, go to **Visual Studio 2017-->Tools-->Extensions and Updates-->Online**. Now search for '**TypeScript Definition Generator**'. Install the one created by  by **Mads Kristensen**.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TypeScriptDefinitionGenerator

Comment: Unfortunately, it fails on my PC with error "The custom tool 'DtsGenerator' failed.". It seems I'm not the only one facing this issue: https://github.com/madskristensen/TypeScriptDefinitionGenerator/issues/9
Does it work for you?