# Unable to import a custom cs class in tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, jsx

In my asp.net core application, I received the following error when I try to import the `Actor` class which resides in the folder called `Models`.

[image]

Below, I share the folder structure of the project.

[image]

Below is the configuration file for typscript:

[image]

Any ideas why I should be receiving this error?

Comment: You cannot import C# code from typescript

Comment: @TomCumming then how do I use these model classes?

Comment: the simple way is to just make typescript type declarations with the same shape, I assume you are interoperating with JSON? there are tools to generate these for you like https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator if you are using open api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `C#` classes in typescript. You have to create classes with similar structure in typescript and then use them. Also you can consider using some [tools](http://littlebigtomatoes.com/2016/06/how-to-generate-typescript-classes-from-c-number-like-a-pro/) for generating `ts` classes from `C#`. This [thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957820/how-to-reuse-existing-c-sharp-class-definitions-in-typescript-projects) might be helpful as well.