# How to exclude certain properties as observable using Ko.mapping.fromJSON

Tags: knockout.js

```
var mapping = {  
'observe': ["testProperty"]  
}  
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, mapping);
```

But this is making all the properties in the viewModel as observable.

Comment: As far as I know observable properties are mapped to UI elements so that they are always in sync with eachother. So why would want to exclude a property from becoming a observable ?

Comment: For example Model has 10 properties. From those properties i want to use 6 properties as textBox fields and 4 properties as readonly fields. So, I want to make 6 properties as observables and 4 properties as unobservable in my ViewModel.

Comment: even for certain properties to appear within a readonly field dont you think there should be some binding b/w properties & UI fields(readonly ) ? what seems like a better approach to me, is to make use of 'Enable' binding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can do this by using `copy` which is straight from Ko Doc's [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) 
Ignoring certain properties being observables using “copy”

If you want the mapping plugin to simply copy the plain properties and not make them observable, use this argument, as shown below.

```
// tell the mapping plugin to handle all other properties normally, but to simply copy this property instead of making it observable

    var mapping = {
        'copy': ["propertyToCopy"]
    }
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

I suggest you to go through this wonderful post **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488208/am-i-overusing-the-knockout-mapping-plugin-by-always-using-it-to-do-my-viewmodel)**

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/5cfa3/96/)** explaining the case

Comment: This code is working for single entity. Can you please explain how to use this copy keyword for collection of objects.

Comment: In the above fiddle example, i want to make b1 as unobservable.